# Format of json data for D3 bundle layout

Tags: json, d3.js, bundle-layout

I am trying to draw a bundle graph very similar to the one in this example, http://bl.ocks.org/1044242#index.html

[image]

I would really appreciate if anyone can help me out to figure out how "readme.json" file is supposed to look like.

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/d/1044242/readme.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/1044242/readme-flare-imports.json

```
    [
      {
        "name":"flare.analytics.cluster.AgglomerativeCluster",
        "size":3938,
        "imports":[
          "flare.animate.Transitioner",
          "flare.vis.data.DataList",
          "flare.util.math.IMatrix",
          "flare.analytics.cluster.MergeEdge",
          "flare.analytics.cluster.HierarchicalCluster",
          "flare.vis.data.Data"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"flare.analytics.cluster.CommunityStructure",
        "size":3812,
        "imports":[
          "flare.analytics.cluster.HierarchicalCluster",
          "flare.animate.Transitioner",
          "flare.vis.data.DataList",
          "flare.analytics.cluster.MergeEdge",
          "flare.util.math.IMatrix"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"flare.analytics.cluster.HierarchicalCluster",
        "size":6714,
        "imports":[
          "flare.vis.data.EdgeSprite",
          "flare.vis.data.NodeSprite",
          "flare.vis.data.DataList",
          "flare.vis.data.Tree",
          "flare.util.Arrays",
          "flare.analytics.cluster.MergeEdge",
          "flare.util.Sort",
          "flare.vis.operator.Operator",
          "flare.util.Property",
          "flare.vis.data.Data"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"flare.analytics.cluster.MergeEdge",
        "size":743,
        "imports":[

        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"flare.analytics.graph.BetweennessCentrality",
        "size":3534,
        "imports":[
          "flare.animate.Transitioner",
          "flare.vis.data.NodeSprite",
          "flare.vis.data.DataList",
          "flare.util.Arrays",
          "flare.vis.data.Data",
          "flare.util.Property",
          "flare.vis.operator.Operator"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"flare.analytics.graph.LinkDistance",
        "size":5731,
        "imports":[
          "flare.animate.Transitioner",
          "flare.vis.data.NodeSprite",
          "flare.vis.data.EdgeSprite",
          "flare.analytics.graph.ShortestPaths",
          "flare.vis.data.Data",
          "flare.util.Property",
          "flare.vis.operator.Operator"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"flare.analytics.graph.MaxFlowMinCut",
        "size":7840,
        "imports":[
          "flare.animate.Transitioner",
          "flare.vis.data.NodeSprite",
          "flare.vis.data.EdgeSprite",
          "flare.vis.data.Data",
          "flare.util.Property",
          "flare.vis.operator.Operator"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"flare.analytics.graph.ShortestPaths",
        "size":5914,
        "imports":[
          "flare.vis.data.EdgeSprite",
          "flare.vis.data.NodeSprite",
          "flare.animate.Transitioner",
          "flare.vis.operator.Operator",
          "flare.util.heap.HeapNode",
          "flare.util.heap.FibonacciHeap",
          "flare.util.Property",
          "flare.vis.data.Data"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"flare.analytics.graph.SpanningTree",
        "size":3416,
        "imports":[
          "flare.animate.Transitioner",
          "flare.vis.data.NodeSprite",
          "flare.vis.operator.IOperator",
          "flare.vis.Visualization",
          "flare.vis.data.TreeBuilder",
          "flare.vis.operator.Operator"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"flare.analytics.optimization.AspectRatioBanker",
        "size":7074,
        "imports":[
          "flare.animate.Transitioner",
          "flare.util.Arrays",
          "flare.vis.data.DataSprite",
          "flare.scale.Scale",
          "flare.vis.axis.CartesianAxes",
          "flare.vis.Visualization",
          "flare.util.Property",
          "flare.vis.operator.Operator"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"flare.animate.Easing",
        "size":17010,
        "imports":[
          "flare.animate.Transition"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"flare.animate.FunctionSequence",
        "size":5842,
        "imports":[
          "flare.util.Maths",
          "flare.animate.Transition",
          "flare.util.Arrays",
          "flare.animate.Sequence",
          "flare.animate.Transitioner"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"flare.animate.interpolate.ArrayInterpolator",
        "size":1983,
        "imports":[
          "flare.util.Arrays",
          "flare.animate.interpolate.Interpolator"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"flare.animate.interpolate.ColorInterpolator",
        "size":2047,
        "imports":[
          "flare.animate.interpolate.Interpolator"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"flare.animate.interpolate.DateInterpolator",
        "size":1375,
        "imports":[
          "flare.animate.interpolate.Interpolator"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"flare.animate.interpolate.Interpolator",
        "size":8746,
        "imports":[
          "flare.animate.interpolate.NumberInterpolator",
          "flare.animate.interpolate.ColorInterpolator",
          "flare.animate.interpolate.PointInterpolator",
          "flare.animate.interpolate.ObjectInterpolator",
          "flare.animate.interpolate.MatrixInterpolator",
          "flare.animate.interpolate.RectangleInterpolator",
          "flare.animate.interpolate.DateInterpolator",
          "flare.util.Property",
          "flare.animate.interpolate.ArrayInterpolator"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"flare.animate.interpolate.MatrixInterpolator",
        "size":2202,
        "imports":[
          "flare.animate.interpolate.Interpolator"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"flare.animate.interpolate.NumberInterpolator",
        "size":1382,
        "imports":[
          "flare.animate.interpolate.Interpolator"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"flare.animate.interpolate.ObjectInterpolator",
        "size":1629,
        "imports":[
          "flare.animate.interpolate.Interpolator"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"flare.animate.interpolate.PointInterpolator",
        "size":1675,
        "imports":[
          "flare.animate.interpolate.Interpolator"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"flare.animate.interpolate.RectangleInterpolator",
        "size":2042,
        "imports":[
          "flare.animate.interpolate.Interpolator"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"flare.animate.ISchedulable",
        "size":1041,
        "imports":[
          "flare.animate.Scheduler"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"flare.animate.Parallel",
        "size":5176,
        "imports":[
          "flare.animate.Easing",
          "flare.animate.Transition",
          "flare.util.Arrays"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"flare.animate.Pause",
        "size":449,
        "imports":[
          "flare.animate.Transition"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"flare.animate.Scheduler",
        "size":5593,
        "imports":[
          "flare.animate.ISchedulable",
          "flare.animate.Pause",
          "flare.animate.Transition"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"flare.animate.Sequence",
        "size":5534,
        "imports":[
          "flare.animate.Easing",
          "flare.util.Maths",
          "flare.animate.Transition",
          "flare.util.Arrays"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"flare.animate.Transition",
        "size":9201,
        "imports":[
          "flare.animate.Transitioner",
          "flare.animate.TransitionEvent",
          "flare.animate.Scheduler",
          "flare.animate.Pause",
          "flare.animate.Parallel",
          "flare.animate.Easing",
          "flare.animate.Sequence",
          "flare.animate.ISchedulable",
          "flare.util.Maths",
          "flare.animate.Tween"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"flare.animate.Transitioner",
        "size":19975,
        "imports":[
          "flare.util.IValueProxy",
          "flare.animate.Parallel",
          "flare.animate.Easing",
          "flare.animate.Sequence",
          "flare.animate.Transition",
          "flare.animate.Tween",
          "flare.util.Property"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"flare.animate.TransitionEvent",
        "size":1116,
        "imports":[
          "flare.animate.Transition"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"flare.animate.Tween",
        "size":6006,
        "imports":[
          "flare.animate.Transitioner",
          "flare.animate.Transition",
          "flare.animate.interpolate.Interpolator",
          "flare.util.Property"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"flare.data.converters.Converters",
        "size":721,
        "imports":[
          "flare.data.converters.IDataConverter",
          "flare.data.converters.GraphMLConverter",
          "flare.data.converters.JSONConverter",
          "flare.data.converters.DelimitedTextConverter"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"flare.data.converters.DelimitedTextConverter",
        "size":4294,
        "imports":[
          "flare.data.DataSet",
          "flare.data.DataUtil",
          "flare.data.DataTable",
          "flare.data.converters.IDataConverter",
          "flare.data.DataSchema",
          "flare.data.DataField"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"flare.data.converters.GraphMLConverter",
        "size":9800,
        "imports":[
          "flare.data.DataSet",
          "flare.data.DataUtil",
          "flare.data.DataTable",
          "flare.data.converters.IDataConverter",
          "flare.data.DataSchema",
          "flare.data.DataField"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"flare.data.converters.IDataConverter",
        "size":1314,
        "imports":[
          "flare.data.DataSet",
          "flare.data.DataSchema"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"flare.data.converters.JSONConverter",
        "size":2220,
        "imports":[
          "flare.data.DataSet",
          "flare.data.DataUtil",
          "flare.data.DataTable",
          "flare.data.converters.IDataConverter",
          "flare.data.DataSchema",
          "flare.data.DataField",
          "flare.util.Property"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"flare.data.DataField",
        "size":1759,
        "imports":[
          "flare.data.DataUtil"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"flare.data.DataSchema",
        "size":2165,
        "imports":[
          "flare.data.DataField",
          "flare.util.Arrays"
        ]
      },
.
.
.
      {
        "name":"flare.vis.Visualization",
        "size":16540,
        "imports":[
          "flare.animate.Transitioner",
          "flare.vis.operator.IOperator",
          "flare.animate.Scheduler",
          "flare.vis.events.VisualizationEvent",
          "flare.vis.data.Tree",
          "flare.vis.events.DataEvent",
          "flare.vis.axis.Axes",
          "flare.vis.axis.CartesianAxes",
          "flare.util.Displays",
          "flare.vis.operator.OperatorList",
          "flare.vis.controls.ControlList",
          "flare.animate.ISchedulable",
          "flare.vis.data.Data"
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Oh, didn't see Mikes comment.